# How to use ArcItem with big stroke

Tags: qt, qml

I'm using Qt Design Studio to define a ArcItem for a Gauge. The ArcItem needs a big Stroke Width to fill correct some background images later. The ArcItem is animated with the Timeline-Module, but when begin and end is same then I have this behavior shown in the image.

[image: ArcItem_Issue1]

I tried then to change the Stroke Width through the Timeline by changing the Stroke Width to -1, if Begin (-125) and End (-125) are equal, but if I'm selecting frame 1, then the ArcItem is out of position.

[image: ArcItem2]

This is frame 2

[image: ArcItem3]

**Question**

How I can solve this issue and keep the Stroke Width?

**Code**

```
import QtQuick 2.12
import maskpietest 1.0
import QtQuick.Studio.Components 1.0
import QtQuick.Studio.Effects 1.0
import QtQuick.Controls 2.15
import QtQuick.Shapes 1.0
import QtQuick.Timeline 1.0

Rectangle {
    id: rectangle
    width: Constants.width
    height: Constants.height
    color: "#00000000"

    layer.enabled: true
    Slider {
        id: slider
        x: 0
        y: 0
        width: 791
        height: 40
        from: 0
        to: 280
        stepSize: 1

    }
    Label{
        id: label
        text: slider.value
        x:8
        y: 46
        font.pointSize: 24

    }

    Rectangle {
        width: 560
        height: 560
        color: "#00000000"

        ArcItem {
            id: arc
            x: 274
            y: 73
            width: 520
            height: 520
            anchors.centerIn: parent
            outlineArc: false
            begin: -125
            fillColor: "#00000000"
            capStyle: 0
            end: -125
            strokeWidth: 100
            strokeColor: "#37c1ff"
            antialiasing: true
        }
    }

    Timeline {
        id: timeline
        currentFrame: slider.value
        animations: [
            TimelineAnimation {
                id: timelineAnimation
                running: false
                duration: 280
                loops: 1
                to: 280
                from: 0
            }
        ]
        endFrame: 280
        enabled: true
        startFrame: 0

        KeyframeGroup {
            target: arc
            property: "end"
            Keyframe {
                frame: 280
                value: 125
            }
        }

        KeyframeGroup {
            target: arc
            property: "strokeWidth"
            Keyframe {
                frame: 0
                value: -1
            }

            Keyframe {
                frame: 1
                value: 100
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of changing the `ArcItem` `strokeWidth` you could just make it invisible on frame 0 and visible at frame 1:

```
KeyframeGroup {
    target: arc
    property: "visible"
    Keyframe {
        frame: 0
        value: false
    }
    Keyframe {
        frame: 1
        value: true
    }
}
```

---

Another solution (and probably the better one) is to set a specific `Keyframe` for the `end` property for frame 0:

```
KeyframeGroup {
    target: arc
    property: "end"
    Keyframe {
        frame: 0
        value: -125
    }
    Keyframe {
        frame: 280
        value: 125
    }
}
```

Comment: Solution 1 will not work because then I have again the offset, but solution 2 seems to work

Comment: I don't get the offset when removing the `KeyframeGroup` for the `strokeWidth`. I think this group is causing it.

Comment: Ok, correct. I will stick to solution 2, because is make most sense and solve the issue.